# How to activate DC motor when a certain temperature is reached?

Tags: transistors, dc-motor

I am a beginner in learning electronic circuits. I was trying to create a circuit on tinkercad that can activate a DC motor when a certain value is reached.

Comment: We need info on temperature sensor.

Comment: The temperature sensor should active the DC motor when temp reaches 40C

Comment: No, right now the temperature sensor is a mystery component. We do not know what any of its pins do. If you also don't know then you are making assumptions about how it works which could be completely wrong (and probably are). It could output the temperature like a thermometer or it could block or conduct current at a certain temperature, we have no idea.

Comment: Instead of "inventing your own", go search online for circuits to learn how this done. I'm suggesting this because what you show now will not work and/or will destroy some components. So in Google search for "temperature control circuit" and select the **images** tab. Then see plenty of circuits. That will also show you that a **diode** is needed across the motor, leaving out this diode will damage the switching transistor.

Comment: ok, thanks I will

Comment: instructables.com is also a good site for circuit examples that are suitable for beginners. Another option is to get a **module** that is "ready for use" you can find such modules on hobby sites, Ebay, Amazon and Aliexpress.

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways to do this. First you need to realize that the motor draws a lot of current, whereas the temperature sensor can handle only a small amount of current. Therefore you need amplification in your circuit.

The simplest and most old-fashioned method is to use a temperature-operated switch, like the one in an old house thermostat. These can have a little piece of bi-metal that operates a switch when the temperature gets above or below a certain point. The switch then drives the motor.

Another option is to use a thermo-couple that drives a regular relay. When the thermo-couple generates enough current, the relais closes (or opens) a switch that in turn drives the motor. This is used e.g. in most older fridges.

A more modern approach is to use a solid-state amplifier like an opamp and/or (power) transistors to amplify the sensor output and drive the motor. Common sensors for this are NTC or PTC resistors or thermo-couples for really high temperatures. The opamp needs to be used in the Schmitt-Trigger configuration. You could also use the venerable CMOS IC's as schmitt-triggers, e.g. the 4050 CMOS buffer. In cases where the motor requires more power than the schmitt-trigger can deliver, power transistors or a relays can be used to amplify the power.

The most complicated solution is to use a micro controller to measure the sensor output and then drive the motor. But that would be overkill — except if that microcontroller is easier to source than an opamp or other schmitt-trigger, or you have other work for it to do.